# System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-remoting

I have a web projects converted from VS 2008 to VS 2013.

The code runs perfectly in 2008, but errors on 2013 at runtime.

From the StartUp project named myWebPages, code will read a web.config in a different project named myRemotingService in the same solution.

Here are portion of the code:

```
Dim rootWebConfig1 As System.Configuration.Configuration

rootWebConfig1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/myRemotingService")

varConnectionString = rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Item("ConnectionString").Value 'Error on this line
```

But when I copy the web.config from myRemotingService to myWebPages. and change the code to:

```
rootWebConfig1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/myWebPages")
varConnectionString = rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Item("ConnectionString").Value
```

Works fine, but I want the web.config be place in myRemotingService because I'm going to build more myWebPages similar projects.

What is wrong with the code?

Thanks

There error is : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I also run some code that I get from the internet

```
rootWebConfig1 =
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/myRemotingService")

Dim appSettings As KeyValueConfigurationCollection =
rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings

Console.WriteLine("[appSettings for app at: {0}]", "/myRemotingService")

Dim key As String
For Each key In appSettings.AllKeys
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Value: {1}", _
        key, appSettings(key).Value)
Next key
```

but the length of the appSettings.count is 0

Comment: "but errors on 2013 at runtime." what's the error?

Comment: The error is : Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I got it by putting the ~ character.

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/myRemotingService")
```

It's working now.